# Terminology for a "studentized" random variable?

Tags: references, random-variable, terminology

Let $X_{1}, \dots, X_{n}$ be i.i.d. ramdom variables having mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. I wonder if the "studentized" $X_{i}$, the sample version of standardized $X_{i}$ where $\mu$ is replaced with the sample average and $\sigma$ is replaced with a sample standard deviation, admits a relatively canonical terminology in literature?

In my shallow opinion,
the term "studentized" is informative but would cost some possibilities of confusion. So a terminology, if it exists, is sought.

The following is in response to a question raised in a comment below. To avoid introducing too many symbols, I described it in plain English. If this helps: If 
$$
\frac{X_{i} - \mu}{\sigma}
$$
is called the standardized $X_{i}$,
if $\bar{X}$ denotes the sample average,
and if $s$ denotes the sample standard deviation under consideration,
then I call
$$
\frac{X_{i} - \bar{X}}{s}
$$
the studentized $X_{i}$ above for reference ease.

Comment: Can you give a specific example, to explain what you exactly mean with these 'replacements', and with 'sample version of a variable $X_i $'. (note the value $\bar x / s_x $ is called the t-score, which contrasts with z-score, did you think about something like that?)

Comment: @MartijnWeterings, Update is available.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. Is this about computing a z-statistic or t-statistic (as used in z-test and t-test), or is this about normalization (I notice now you explicitly used the term 'standardized')? What confuses me (and the formula's don't solve this) are the random variables $X_1, ... , X_n$. Is $X_i$ a random variable (e.g. $X_i$ is the length of a person from population $i$) or is $X_i$ a specific member of a sample (e.g. $X_i$ is the length of person $i$ in the sample)?

Comment: A new thing: it might be also useful to give examples/explanation where/how you wish to apply the term 'studentized'? If you use it in some context of defining confidence intervals (or anything else where distinction between the distributions normal/t is important) then it might be useful (e.g. see studentized residuals). If you use it a context like pca where one just seeks to roughly normalize the vectors then it will be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the comments in the original post are worthy as an answer. I summarize as follows.

Original post asks whether $\dfrac{x_i-\bar{x}}{s}$ can be referred to as "studentized value of $x_i$"; since $\dfrac{X_i-\mu}{\sigma}$ is referred to as "standardized value of $X_i$". The names are referring to Student's t and standard normal distribution, respectively.

---

"Studentized" in this case may as well just be called just "standardized", unless in cases where distinction between t-distribution and normal distribution is important e.g. studentized residuals. Most of the time it will just add confusion and it's better to just use the term "standardized".

Comment: +1 I typically say "Standardized using the sample mean and sample standard deviation." Depending on the audience I might say "*z* transformation" or "*t* transformation" to convey the distinction.